# What function satisfies $f(x)+f(−x)=f(x^2)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

What function satisfies $f(x)+f(−x)=f(x^2)$?

$f(x)=0$ is obviously a solution to the above functional equation.

We can assume f is continuous or differentiable or similar (if needed).

Comment: $f(0) = 0$ does not hold with $\log|x|$

Comment: maybe you can consider $f(x)+f(-x)=2f(x)=f(x^2)$?

Comment: @hkmather802 : Where exactly did that come from?

Comment: All even functions $f(x)$ obeys the rule $f(x)+f(-x)=2f(x)$. So we may try to find some even $f(x)$ where $2f(x)=f(x^2)$

Comment: Is it given that $f$ must have domain and codomain $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @hkmather802 I doubt a continuous, defined-everywhere one exists. (Of course, $\ln\lvert x\rvert$ works, but it's not defined at $0$.)

Comment: Fairly certain that the only sufficiently "nice" ones (continuous, infinitely differentiable) are ones like $\ln(1+x+x^2)$ or $\ln(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)$.

Comment: (or linear combinations of those)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Define $f(x)$ any way you want for $x > 0$, then define $f(-x) = f(x^2) - f(x)$ also for $x>0$. If you want continuity, make sure that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Where do you know that if the limit exists, then there is another solution other than trivial one??!!

Comment: Since you can start with any continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ with $f(0)=0$ to get a continuous function on the whole real line, there are infinitely many continuous solutions. If you can prove that $f=0$ is the only solution, then the proof or the statement of the problem is wrong.

Comment: For example, let $f(x)=x^2$ for $x>0$, $f(x)=x^4-x^2$ for $x<0$, and $f(0)=0$. This gives an explicit solution, and it's easy to check that it's continuous.

Comment: Another example: let $f(x) = x$ if $x\geq 0$ and $f(x) = x^2 + x$ if $x<0$.

Comment: That's OK, I made a little mistake in my calculations...thanks for observations...+1

Answer (score 2):

Give f(x) = ln(|x|)  a try in your equation

Comment: This was mentioned in the comments, and is not continuous at 0. (It's not even defined at 0, but the point is that no extension of the function to the whole real line is continuous.)

Comment: Actually the question doesn't specify the domain. So also the function $f:\{-1,1\}\to\{0,1\}$ with $f(-1)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ satisfies the given requirements.

Comment: @user28111, the comment proposing $\log|x|$ was deleted (only a reply remains).  And the question doesn't insist on continuity.  The only thing missing here, I'd say, is to extend $f$ by defining $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to put my comment as an answer.

$\ln|1-x|$ seems to work:
$$\ln|1-x|+\ln|1+x|=\ln|1-x^2|$$
Similarly, so does $\ln|1-x^3|$ (or any odd exponent).

Also, any linear combination of these works, as you can check. Thus:
$$\ln(1+x+x^2)$$
works because it's equal to $\ln|1-x^3|-\ln|1-x|$. The example of $\ln(1+x+x^2)$ is nice because it's defined, continuous, and infinitely differentiable everywhere.

As far as I know, if you want it to be defined everywhere, continuous, and infinitely differentiable, this sort of thing is the only possible solution.